# Usando Cache do Laravel

Tags: laravel, cache

Gostaria de saber se a maneira que estou trabalhando com cache está correta e se tem algo mais prático para isso.

Segue o código:

```
<?php
namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers;

use Cache;
use Auth;

class Network extends Controller
{
    public function teste()
    {
        if( ! Cache::has('user') ) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            Cache::store('file')->put('user', $user, 10);
        } else {
            $user = Cache::get('user');
        }

        return view('cms::user', [
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }
}
```

Grato pela compreensão.

Comment: Está certo @Raank!, só muda um pouco quando quiser usar dados de banco ! `$value = Cache::get('key', function() {
    return DB::table(...)->get();
});` que seria dessa forma!

Comment: Não vejo problemas no uso do cache, a única coisa que eu faria é mudar o local onde você faz essa verificação e aplicaria os padrões da PSR-4.